# show multiple items using list xtype in horizental view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, horizontallist, sencha-touch-2.3

I'm new to sencha and I need to show two or more record in one row

```
{
            xtype: 'list',
            flex: 1,
            cls:'home-page-class',
            itemTpl:'<img  src="{image}">',
            store: 'HomePage',
            itemCls:'details',

            useSimpleItems: false,
            variableHeights: true,
            infinite: true,
            disableSelection: true,
            allowDeselect: false,
            scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,

            itemHeight:80,
            plugins: [
                { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging', autoPaging: true},
                { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh'}


              ],
}
```

I tried to play with CSS but sencha create empty items showing it like this [image: empty cells]

And I can't change to xtype dataview because I need the listpaging plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that to remove some parameters and add inline:true,this work out for me

> {
>               xtype: 'list',
>               flex: 1,
>               cls:'home-page-class',
>               itemTpl:'',
>               store: 'HomePage',
>               itemCls:'details',
>
> ```
>         //useSimpleItems: false,
>         //variableHeights: true,
>         //infinite: true,
>         disableSelection: true,
>         allowDeselect: false,
>         scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
>         inline:true,
>         itemHeight:80,
>         plugins: [
>             { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging', autoPaging: true},
>             { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh'}
>
>
>           ], }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is a trick, change your itemTpl 
from

```
itemTpl:'<img  src="{image}">',
```

to

```
itemTpl:'<img id="img1" src="{image1}"><img id="img2" src="{image2}">',
```

then set up event listeners to these objects if needed.

Comment: thats not what I want, the single cell may have title, date added and so on So it will not work